# Not able attach click event for a button using Javascript oop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working on attaching a click event on a button which is having class "nextPage", but its not working. Let me show you the code.

```
function myContent() {

}

myContent.prototype.clickNext = function() {
alert("clicked");    
};


var objMyContent = new myContent();

var el = document.getElementsByClassName('nextPage');
el.onclick=objMyContent.clickNext();
```

Please take a look into it. Please let me know where I did mistake.

Comment: Don't edit answers into your question, please.

Comment: Ok. Cool. What went wrong even after changing it to clickNext from clickNext()?

Comment: I found the other problem, gimme a sec to edit my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the function, not execute it, when assigning the click handler.

Instead of:

```
el.onclick = objMyContent.clickNext();
```

Use this:

```
el.onclick = objMyContent.clickNext;
```

The first piece of code executes `clickNext`, and assigns it's return value to `el.onclick`.
 The second line assigns a reference to the `clickNext` function to `el.onclick`, instead. (Which is what you want)

Also, `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` (Which is basically an array of HTML elements).
You'll need to assign the click handler to each found element in that collection:

```
for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
    el[i].onclick = objMyContent.clickNext;
}
```

Comment: Changed to it. Still not getting the alert

Comment: Thank you. I've one more question. As we add class to a table row using for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                $('#tblAllMessages tbody tr:nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass('active');
            } using jQuery. I'm not able to do the same using javascript. Can you help me regarding this?

Comment: @NizamAli: That's a problem for a new question.

Comment: Yeah. I can't post a new question until next 90 min. That's why I'm asking here. Hope you understand.

Comment: Yea, I understand, but the answer would be too long for these comments.

Answer (score 0):

iterate the array and the assign the onclick event

```
var objMyContent = new myContent();

var el = document.getElementsByClassName('nextPage'); for(var i=0;i<el.length;i++) el[i].onclick=objMyContent.clickNext;
```

Comment: Thanks dude. But, may I know why should I iterate it? What's the purpose of it?